# How can I do a string search in solr that allows wildcards, whitespace characters, and is case insensitive?

Tags: solr

I am attempting to run the following query against my solr system:

```
((((subtype:place) AND name:fis*) AND addressPostal:98007) AND addressLine1:14320\ 21*)
```

This query is meant to search for businesses that have the first 3 characters of the name `fis` and the first 8 characters of the address to be `14320 21`.

This returns no matches.  However if I change `fis*` to `Fis*` it returns the correct match.  After further investigation it appears that string types are case sensitive.

I then when to try to define my fields so that they would be case insensitive, allow wildcard searches (or at least starts with searches), and not break on whitespace.  Unfortunately I have failed.

The closest I have gotten so far is:

```
<fieldType name="lowerCaseString" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

With this I can do `((((subtype:place) AND name:fis*) AND addressPostal:98007) AND addressLine1:14320*)` and get the correct match, but I am unable to do the full 8 characters for address search due to the space (and since most addresses only have a few digits before their first space, this is a major issue).

The addressLine1 search needs to be case insensitive too, as I need `st == ST == St`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Make a text field with the KeywordTokenizerFactory. This tokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire input string is preserved as a single token. So it will be like having a lowercase string field:

```
<fieldType name="lowerCaseString" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to keep the type of your field as string, but lower-case the value when you index the data. Then lower-case the query from the client side too.